# How to edit a DT column and save the changes to trigger calculations in dependent columns?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt

I'm creating a shiny app that will be used by multiple people to see and edit data in a table format. I want the user to be able to edit one or more columns at a time. I've been using the DT package in R to do this, but I can't figure out how to save the edits made in the data table. This is crucial because there are dependant values in other columns that need to be recalculated.

If I set editable = TRUE I can change the value in one cell, but that is much too slow. When I set editable = "column" or "all" I can edit multiple cells quickly, but then the edits won't save, no matter how many times I hit return.

In the example below, all I'm trying to do is print the edited values to the console. If the values appear in the _cell_edit variable then I can use the editData function to save the changes.

I haven't found anything useful on StackOverflow yet, but I did find the following two blog posts helpful.

https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/03/29/dt-0-4/
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

```
# TEST APP DT

library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("save", "Click to Save Changes"),
  DTOutput("dt_table")

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- 
    data.frame(
      A = c("Ones", "Twos", "Threes", "Total"),
      B = c(1, 2, 3, 6),
      C = c(1, 2, 3, 6),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    ) %>% mutate(D = B + C)

  live = reactiveValues(df = NULL)

  observe({
    live$df <- data
  })

  output$dt_table <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      live$df, 
      rownames = FALSE,
      editable = list(
        target = "column",
        disable = list(columns = c(1, 3))
      )
    )
  })

  proxy_dt_table <- dataTableProxy("dt_table")

  observeEvent(input$save, {
    info = input$dt_table_cell_edit
    str(info)
    row = info$row
    col = info$col
    val = info$value

    print(paste0("Row: ", row))
    print(paste0("Col: ", col))
    print(paste0("Val: ", val))

  })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```
Right now, the values in the _cell_edit variable are empty. 
  NULL
[1] "Row: "
[1] "Col: "
[1] "Val: "
```

```
I would like to see something like this:
 'data.frame': 200 obs. of 3 variables
[1] "Row: [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]"
[1] "Col: [1, 1, 1, 1, ...]"
[1] "Val: [5, 6, 7, 8, ...]"
```

Comment: You need to hit `CTRL+Enter` to save the changes.

Comment: @GyD is there a way to change that?